# Voltage mode vs. current mode motor

Tags: motor, torque

Regarding voltage vs current mode for a feedback control motor, will operating in current mode have any effect on our torque values provided that we are keeping the speed constant? The motor is a stirrer system i.e. stirring device for mixing which gives us torque.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you control the speed of a motor, the torque will be determined by the characteristics of the driven load. Method of speed control will not have any effect.